# Lumen - modifying the route through middleware

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

So I have an api-version middleware that I use in laravel 5 that I am trying to use in lumen. However it uses `getAction()` and `setAction()` in the middleware which isn't available to lumen ("yet"). If I do `$request->route()[1]` I can get the current route but updating that with the new route does no good. I have thought about cloning the request and modifying it but I can't tell what part of the request object I would need to "update".

Here are my routes:

```
$app->group(['middleware' => ['api-version']], function() use ($app) {
    $app->get('users', '{api-namespace}\UsersController@index');
    $app->get('vips/{per_page?}', '{api-namespace}\VipsController@index');
    $app->get('vip/{id}/profile', '{api-namespace}\VipsController@showProfile');
    $app->get('vip/{id}', '{api-namespace}\VipsController@show');
});
```

Can anyone tell me how i can update the request with my simple route update?

Comment: So, you want one route to redirect to another route?

Comment: I have added in my routes for a little clarification. As you can see the "uses" is {api-namespace}\(controller)@(action). The middleware rips api-version header and compares it to a whitelist mapping. So you end up with a "uses" of v1 or v2 or v3\\(controller)@(action). This allows me to version my API in a restful manner

Comment: The problem is that the middleware I use to do this in Laravel 5 uses $route->getAction() and $route->setAction() to grab / modify / replace the route action. This isn't available in Lumen so i am looking for alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this in my search for a solution. Here's what I came up with using middleware in Lumen 5.4.

First, I created an ExtractApiVersionMiddleware that extracts the version from the Accept header. I used the accept header because not all headers passed are trusted and it is becoming "Best Practice": to pass API versions in this manner:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ExtractApiVersionMiddleware
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param  \Closure $next
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $app = app();
    $version = "0";
    foreach (explode(';', $request->header('accept')) as $frag) {
        if (stristr($frag, "version=")) {
            $version = str_replace("version=", "", $frag);
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($version != 0) {
        $app->group(['namespace' => "App\Http\Controllers\V{$version}\Reductions"],
            function () use ($app, $version) {
            require base_path() . "/routes/web/v{$version}.php";
        });
    } else {
        $app->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\V0'], function () use ($app, $version) {
            require base_path() . "/routes/web/v0.php";
        });
    }

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

Second, I namespaced my code according to versions (the legacy codebase hasn't died yet).

Third, I pass the version that the call uses in the Accept header
`Accept: application/json;version=1`

Fourth, I have separate route files for each supported version. So, instead of having a web.php for all my routes, I created a web folder under routes and I placed my version files in there `v0.php & v1.php`

So, when I make a request, the Middleware extracts the API version and based on the version number enables the appropriate route group. This keeps the versions clean and separate but still enables me to get 'creative' with my Models.

Hope this helps. I had to apply this solution because I wasn't sure about using Dingo API in pre-release form